# Export xml file with order data on woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, woocommerce, phpseclib

I need to export a xml file with the details of the order to my local machine.

**I have two problems:**

1. I used the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook but it fires *everytime* the user visits the order summary. Instead I now use `woocommerce_new_order`. But when there's an error while storing the xml file, I get an *empty error box* on my checkout page. **How can I catch an error firing during the `woocommerce_new_order` hook and show it in the error box with php?**
2. My server has no ssh2 installed so I tried to use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It works like a charm when I run it in a sample file but when I call it during the `woocommerce_new_order` hook I *can't connect* to my local machine. I don't get any errors and the site just *ends* there. **Is there a way to connect to a local windows machine that is working during the `woocommerce_new_order` hook?**

This is my code so far:

```php
function save_xml($order_id) {
    set_include_path(getcwd());
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($host);
    if (!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
        // This is where I need to send an error to woocommerce
    } else {
        $ssh->exec($run); // Here I run some command
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'save_xml', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 0):

Hey not sure if you have solved this?

But if all of the orders go to processing before you want to send them you could use

```
woocommerce_order_status_processing
```

hook as it only fires once and shouldn't leave a square on your thank you page.